# Python requests how to know what parameter to pass

Tags: python, python-requests

I have the following code. I am trying to access to https://api.github.com/users/jtorre94 via the requests library.

```
import requests
api_url = "https://api.github.com/users"
response = requests.get(api_url, params={'login': 'jtorre94'})
response.json()
```

However, the response is something I do not recognize at all, like if it was not filtered by the jtorre94 parameter.

```
[{'login': 'mojombo',
  'id': 1,
  'node_id': 'MDQ6VXNlcjE=',
  'avatar_url': 'https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1?v=4',
  'gravatar_id': '',
  'url': 'https://api.github.com/users/mojombo',
  'html_url': 'https://github.com/mojombo',
  'followers_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/followers',
  'following_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/following{/other_user}',
  'gists_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/gists{/gist_id}',
  'starred_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/starred{/owner}{/repo}',
  'subscriptions_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/subscriptions',
  'organizations_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/orgs',
  'repos_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/repos',
  'events_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/events{/privacy}',
  'received_events_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/received_events',
  'type': 'User',
  'site_admin': False},
 {'login': 'defunkt',
  'id': 2,
  'node_id': 'MDQ6VXNlcjI=',
  'avatar_url': 'https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/2?v=4',
  'gravatar_id': '',
  'url': 'https://api.github.com/users/defunkt',
  'html_url': 'https://github.com/defunkt',
  'followers_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/defunkt/followers',
  'following_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/defunkt/following{/...
```

How can I retrieve the json for username jtorre94?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append it to the url as you already tried with your browser:

```
import requests
user = 'jtorre94'
api_url = f"https://api.github.com/users/{user}"
response = requests.get(api_url)
response.json()
```

Output:

```
{'login': 'jtorre94',
 'id': 76944588,
 'node_id': 'MDQ6VXNlcjc2OTQ0NTg4',
 'avatar_url': 'https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/76944588?v=4',
 'gravatar_id': '',
 'url': 'https://api.github.com/users/jtorre94',
 'html_url': 'https://github.com/jtorre94',
 'followers_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/jtorre94/followers',
 'following_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/jtorre94/following{/other_user}',
 'gists_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/jtorre94/gists{/gist_id}',
 'starred_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/jtorre94/starred{/owner}{/repo}',
 'subscriptions_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/jtorre94/subscriptions',
 'organizations_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/jtorre94/orgs',
 'repos_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/jtorre94/repos',
 'events_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/jtorre94/events{/privacy}',
 'received_events_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/jtorre94/received_events',
 'type': 'User',
 'site_admin': False,
 'name': None,
 'company': None,
 'blog': '',
 'location': None,
 'email': None,
 'hireable': None,
 'bio': None,
 'twitter_username': None,
 'public_repos': 4,
 'public_gists': 0,
 'followers': 0,
 'following': 0,
 'created_at': '2021-01-04T10:11:25Z',
 'updated_at': '2022-07-23T11:17:18Z'}
```

Comment: What would be the use case then for passing params as an input?

Comment: @JaviTorre. There is no case to use parameters when you get a [user](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/users/users?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-a-user). However if you want to retrieve some [information about user](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/users/users?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-contextual-information-for-a-user), you have to specify the `subject_type` parameter (but you need an api key).